# C# win form transparency

Tags: c#, png, transparency

I am using C# to make my desktop applications.
But I want to make more graphical applications that have full transparency backgrounds and different levels of transparency for picture box controls.
Basically, not cookie cutter opacity of removing a solid color.

How can I accomplish this with C#?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @Drake I suggest WPF. Otherwise, you can play with `Graphics`.

Comment: If you are using winform, you can do this only through gdi+, they are quite a hack. Otherwise you have to use WPF, where it's really easier.

Comment: I am using winform, but I can use WPF if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, just go ahead with WPF. [This](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) gived me a good start point.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/XparentFormsCS10282007212944PM/XparentFormsCS.aspx

also

form2.Opacity = .x; where x is percentage of transparency 
or
transparency can be directly edited in appearance property of form in case you are using VSTO